# Python ImportError: cannot import name XXXX

Tags: python, python-import

I am very new to python (just started reading Learn Python the Hard Way...) and couldn't understand why I got this rather infamous import error. I have seen a lot other import error posts but none of them is the same as mine (at least I didn't find the same post).

I have a project directory called `ex48 (D:\LearnPython\projects\ex48)`, inside it there is a **sub-folder** also called ex48 e.g. `D:\LearnPython\projects\ex48\ex48`(is this bad practice to name directory like this?). There is a `ex48.py` file in which a very simple class, say class is called `XXXX`, is defined. I have a `ex48_test.py` file containing some simple unit tests; in this test file if I do `from ex48.ex48 import XXXX` then everything works fine when the `ex48.py` file is in the sub-folder (`D:\LearnPython\projects\ex48\ex48`).

Now what I don't understand is why it would give me an `Import Error: cannot import name XXXX` if I put the `ex48.py` in the main project folder e.g. (`D:\LearnPython\projects\ex48`) and do the import as `from ex48 import XXXX`.

By the way, the test file (ex48_test.py) is in `D:\LearnPython\projects\ex48\tests` and I am running the tests using `nose` package.

Comment: does your subfolder have `__init__.py` ?

Comment: LPTHW is not a great resource for new learners imho ...

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes it does. Is this why?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I am nearly finishing the book though I didn't do everything as the author asked:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have a folder by the same name `ex48` which has an `__init__.py` inside it, making it a valid Python package.

So when you are doing `from ex48 import <something>`, Python is importing the `ex48` package, and them trying to import `<something>` from it , but something is not found in the package (`__init__.py` of the package) , hence it gives you the `ImportError`.

I am guessing your directory structure looks something like -

```
ex48/
     ex48.py
     ex48/
          __init__.py
```

So from the main folder when you are importing `ex48` , it actually ends up importing the `ex48` package. You can verify this by doing the following in your `ex48_test.py` file -

```
import ex48
print(ex48.__file__)
```

This should be importing the `__init__.py` file inside your `ex48` folder.

The solution would be to rename your folder such that it does not conflict with your `ex48` module.

Comment: you are absolutely right! I shall read a bit more about how Python package works which is the main reason why I couldn't understand this error. Many thanks.